# Not enough free disk space for upgrading, need help

Tags: upgrade, disk-usage, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to update my distribution and get the following error:

[image: Error message]

Outpuf of `df -H` command is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            8.4G   13k  8.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.7G  1.5M  1.7G   1% /run
/dev/sda7        22G   21G  357M  99% /
none            4.1k     0  4.1k   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
none            8.4G   13M  8.4G   1% /run/shm
none            105M   21k  105M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       105M   40M   66M  38% /media/System_Reserved
/dev/sda8       7.0G  2.3G  4.4G  34% /home
```

Output of of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` is:

```
rc  linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic               3.11.0-18.32                                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.11.0-20-generic               3.11.0-20.35                                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.11.0-22-generic               3.11.0-22.38                                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-101-generic              3.13.0-101.148                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic               3.13.0-27.50                                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-29-generic               3.13.0-29.53                                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-30-generic               3.13.0-30.55                                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic               3.13.0-35.62                                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic               3.13.0-43.72                                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic               3.13.0-44.73                                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic               3.13.0-74.118                                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-77-generic               3.13.0-77.121                                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic               3.13.0-79.123                                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic               3.13.0-83.127                                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-85-generic               3.13.0-85.129                                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-87-generic               3.13.0-87.133                                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic               3.13.0-88.135                                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic         3.11.0-18.32                                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.11.0-20-generic         3.11.0-20.35                                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.11.0-22-generic         3.11.0-22.38                                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic        3.13.0-101.148                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-27-generic         3.13.0-27.50                                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-29-generic         3.13.0-29.53                                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-30-generic         3.13.0-30.55                                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic         3.13.0-35.62                                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic         3.13.0-43.72                                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic         3.13.0-44.73                                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic         3.13.0-74.118                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic         3.13.0-77.121                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic         3.13.0-79.123                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-83-generic         3.13.0-83.127                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic         3.13.0-85.129                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-87-generic         3.13.0-87.133                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-88-generic         3.13.0-88.135                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                         3.13.0.101.109
```

Output of `cat /etc/fstab` is:

```
#Entry for /dev/sda7 :
UUID=570e803b-2793-4396-9adb-4ffc1c59f780       /       ext4    errors=remount-ro   01
#Entry for /dev/sda8 :
UUID=ce0bd6fa-46e8-4a2f-8f9d-a6b3fc998dd0       /home   ext4    defaults        0   2
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=DA8C2D5E8C2D3703   /media/System_Reserved  ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 00
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=D4F171ECA3AB6795   /media/data     ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8     0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=7EF43014F42FCCE9   /media/windows  ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8     0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda6 :
UUID=b0ba614a-e26b-4a7d-9a7e-6323ec2caa86       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Output of `sudo blkid -o list`:

```
device                                           fs_type         label            mount point                                          UUID                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
/dev/sda1                                        ntfs            System Reserved  /media/System_Reserved                               DA8C2D5E8C2D3703                     
/dev/sda2                                        ntfs                             (not mounted)                                        18C6E2D8C6E2B4E2                     
/dev/sda3                                        ntfs                             (not mounted)                                        347890A478906700                     
/dev/sda5                                        ntfs            data             (not mounted)                                        BCEC6B90B216E1AF                     
/dev/sda6                                        swap                             (not mounted)                                        563a9a97-7431-4d46-b98b-890f445cb44f 
/dev/sda7                                        ext4            root             /                                                    570e803b-2793-4396-9adb-4ffc1c59f780 
/dev/sda8                                        ext4            home                     /home                                                ce0bd6fa-46e8-4a2f-8f9d-a6b3fc998dd0
```

Also, it seems that /root using 20GB, which is strange.
Under `/root` , output of `du -hc --max-depth 1` is:

```
123M    ./.wine
8.0K    ./.hplip
4.0K    ./.aptitude
16K     ./.p2
4.0K    ./.cache
20K     ./.kde
8.0K    ./.local
12K     ./.dbus
76K     ./.config
12K     ./.wireshark
8.0K    ./.vim
548K    ./.eclipse
24K     ./.synaptic
11G     .
11G     total
```

"total 11G" Is very weird because on `df -H` output i can see 20G used.

Plus, after using `du -sk * | sort -rn` in the root dir, i can weird tmp jibbrish which i'm not sure how to get rid of, such as:

```
2510452 tmp_iFCz_-4CdwKM9fqLx8lLungTEU7sknWlG0_9SlbTPGFFCc5Kt.bY.Nhh4IzgdpEd0vFCPT5axftza4iKrIb-we5tQhgxhCeGtGfRjDaAcm1JA4MWLNMnTkaQpE3Whn0xVmxNIIqdk8ypRWbb-4.DxqNuok.2U9ahcn8rQKvNbUzfzscAt9oISX-R_1Oc.Lmsa 0TjT0I3yAKBiOi4e5k0L7R-NnHZklgPkClQf3EMcPuO.AxdMInlEv0k0
```

Which seems to be sort of temp files, but not sure where they come from 
or is it safe to delete them

Output of `ls -lh /root`:

```
total 12G
-rw------- 1 root root 328M אפר 29  2014 tmp2lk3jyGhuXOKS7RP5I.JMyhOBX4HQOjpwfwWGYiiJFocreeUXWYVwoEJFlCDOHv-.SCENOXTzuNINDjKbOtMNYp.zGUM-xGfxYI7YseMPkOf7KsVAX3NDO63a_NRZMt2fpQ.QSE.oPlBdYgfs p-ZqSkdLQCiTijrK6ybR-yavdEWp 4fsAZk3X2iUc6IXt_mJ3cqeG3gAoB8OOsJN5uO7eoBknOx9s4UXJJhf6v5pK2ycdx8rLLHN7XBWx
-rw------- 1 root root 1.4G ינו 19  2015 tmp5R_jIY5jBuBJ3Za0WLjanIQA91sSAqBGrPLlhzkLPibKkgvshk9F8uCtWvMLD17_wJa0.Y9oduIrecqsrQa.1t4FFD36oRjtwDcxSVLDsHGVLuxPMEH_cLZkWBoBM3PP46IF-1SMVNZdpToJGnG3aHnSLvrEX8USkneTLI0-A z1Vbz4kWw-p2bqkQVbWGf580S6Kt2oPDkfE3PTghkdqk5Qkw4nnS.PruZRB2z36nNDh6a8a1Xbh9YyJXt
-rw------- 1 root root 487M אפר 30  2014 tmpaVNUl8cYsTXQfUDOoe4M2kNlbpplpbm8_3rAVPHFh BKJ-5VYSRz-5dSSbSK9QcTovAxoUAZ83U.8ef7u5 qxAVA_1smiHNZyrBdKsYeclXMuS4jOIOlDixKOExoxhOoPTa4nhStH8v-lm7XJ3T2LxELE9FFs6y1FqTz9-e v6bqerQaTj8Xt17WlHOFSvR9U80c9g2oyaAjNChud-UxMh84O nMfyokCRvlrjL1Tmwkfo7SCeKpyvv0Fzd
-rw------- 1 root root 2.4G דצמ 26  2015 tmp_iFCz_-4CdwKM9fqLx8lLungTEU7sknWlG0_9SlbTPGFFCc5Kt.bY.Nhh4IzgdpEd0vFCPT5axftza4iKrIb-we5tQhgxhCeGtGfRjDaAcm1JA4MWLNMnTkaQpE3Whn0xVmxNIIqdk8ypRWbb-4.DxqNuok.2U9ahcn8rQKvNbUzfzscAt9oISX-R_1Oc.Lmsa 0TjT0I3yAKBiOi4e5k0L7R-NnHZklgPkClQf3EMcPuO.AxdMInlEv0k0
-rw------- 1 root root 619M אפר 16  2014 tmpNiKja6SgJU7DuOcb2zB3qns2PrDWVvixVEq-qNm-xBOQn2YcYGk1-pAj-yl-Q3yNfsS  lxGsR1nSTTF14bGbL2KKWHUSn7oPeqgeIoPdO7vbCbdDsz37PCIAz3TapjLNgFw1rmiXIlDVzHi-xzy0kKf8pqwbXG7SJoloyEGKyjXFgkvCEuTQwX iiGlWJkNd8O9DW_hRJ36PpohW.OyongdDRvA4 dI_RnYp7cZtJ.dtU.v0DLd6bz86qJ
-rw------- 1 root root 807M מאי  6  2014 tmpS8tFRtYvVaHRiHoDFKcUWH9DQFNSU OJCXqMjoWYslH9GdmQx0b-31-qMfr8MWU2l_BINma1XUpNdJI0EGeG5evHk4Zzodqig9DBjE44h-pD3QEuojeMemleLeehIttTMuc5foQJF41NQ_dMbfCogVNfkxEe8Bh0-tCC_naa7fT7ladVXi4uavnvknNBUn l7HqNQcPzeooevVrNPq4WnI5FIAjzA6 eE6zGgCLZM18_5Edf95jlNZ1ljmR
-rw------- 1 root root 892M אפר 27  2014 tmpt1jIRtG1tb.E3xmLtd3JoSy9--RrF1_IZHfiFVuD-SlZ5v-cZiOotu22WWHZb2hn_6sRaxSEueH5LlKtzKSd3CEn8 g5b YEfsucyaQYFxEtGiLNqUk4RiaQF_-7BVn_hid6u8LKDq0SFhKI CBvMoyZO EvQ NPDYQsRcr659GX UyaiA_FnazuyaTuZ t9NSCuGnmEY2lWoUpNRiCw2tg 8j_EEuFhbA4CHU0X0UFrBBuvygeE0hl6XQE
-rw------- 1 root root 720M נוב 13 00:28 tmpt20vR7OIW8eput9gKDUKsVvBsvETj95gMpJq8nT4X5mnSmCd6we-GbW1ITbR21 lv6VWZ9IvsrhO5Gl N3ad3Rjew GPCLfP-cRsyUus2_II.AzvRYmtp9aWc4H81qyax2sXgklkRww_4fn41V1JNksobmmgM6Yt6tymgJ8ksVVrQsgAYZmNUH3Gx-c1wAi0Uc40MFq-HMDp3imDToxf_NArHBM98NmF7IR4_LxSk7kgxCDUb2D4mXL eXE
-rw------- 1 root root 495M אפר 27  2014 tmptAJ2hNrDYvRSP0JI6 NBklh4EdXmsAHqtfYF2X9B3rveYGN7xAX4EAx91EDnImZa -.rzonWUt.yBilPTQmlR7i3r-on.A6EuQQ.vc3PePAniRuAM99--cPRo1BI J1qBntSl2nXUEedo6TqD4QUoJmfVbdYyS9QWl13rsAw-EdFqOnYK4mJyorX6rlh9BE3KQ4a zTxFelC2JtNNXyJ4CPpaCH 1JGyxsI6RCASEViAVkR4UoR_F36-f _
-rw------- 1 root root 838M מאי 17  2014 tmpXfg2g_8c6wh-943elGs6iZVFob4FH.BxtCoQPZJzK7MkrL6HKY8BtX6j6_RlR3Gm6ac9rYRJ9h08hMGJlodxvblfn2wWPuP Vk_XtslLJjVefRuDz6EUD3JX5IQY8Hecs4pfHe-Nki3LBTgxFn2_GtOvei8WhRs-M-zq3qn6SiaXFrkDfrmUm788Tmm3lSjpfJi6_PYZeU9iFKBoSPSxqnHSXymHFLZSXEJbYdaXgyb.Wq.L89SQAQTYyF9
-rw------- 1 root root 948M אפר 16  2014 tmpxG9L4a6W2si-X4i4o.HJEkxDrLQp11FtD5rzNrEXTPNTV6Ui54CNE5AuDyREFUIyzDWLhpTGOnFTl1QicEgPqmOwjTCC97PXXjvND8_6LPS9.KgrF7JIfdjMM8nCKumx9oSQjgYSiFFaWalRKVozVddtiYYVNiN36gKMK_GMsXaFJjR HOSC2yoAFk.SV1gOoCi.iXHoYrxfPDZyDe.3Rw.5UMRkX6vDx.wskofM2Ef5ZucokDjwaGQuOhf
-rw------- 1 root root 1.8G נוב 12 19:07 tmpxzSAQ0-FZzUng-nAEhmwS8OjHUm0d2cWbW8QDvdZXDPUBYMVOZTsldv3fJhLjwA3fdImgD-nEB1.rQBk6DSAI7qLZv3sD aQU2-3o5D1MElfohSJ5HBXmAt0L9DC5VbzU1LXzPhf3pjtDk1O73Jt3E9pnr4 P.QebU.MMeGlS2ltwIzX07mCSQ1eJwoOFCDXZ9iKKoioIJpI6lvdLiVGlJPE-qO9TCIIxAa.rrmbiFThOoEuUnc2U4Piptm
```

Any help will be much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your `dpkg -l` shows a lot of removed packages. Try the following:

```
dpkg -l|awk '/^rc/{print $2}' >pkgList
```

should list removed packages that you did not purge. Assuming the previous command went well, you should be able to go with:

```
 cat pkgList | DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive xargs apt-get remove --purge -yf --force-yes
```

Comment: When trying to use your second command i receive the following:

`The following packages will be REMOVED:
    wine1.4*
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.`

Comment: edited my post, adding `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` env var and  `-yf --force-yes` options to apt

Comment: Thanks, it removed only the following:

`ca-certificates-java`

Comment: Allright... New edit: writing our package list to a file, dropping my loop, using xargs instead, ... should purge *all packages* from the list

Comment: Ok, that seemed to purge indeed all packages from the list,

And still, /root has only 437MB free space out of 22GB

Comment: allright... Then probably some `apt-get clean` to purge your cache, but we're now pretty much sure this space isn't used by packages. Next, you may want to run `du -sh` on directories such as `/usr/src`, `/var/log`, `/var/cache`, ...

Comment: clean didn't made a difference also.

`du -sh` output:  /usr/src - 232MB, /var/log - 16MB, /var/cache - 258MB

Those directories also doesn't seem to hold up all the space i'm afraid

Comment: Except for continuing with `du -sh` on top-level directories, then going down the the sub-dirs that use the more space (taking care of excluding /var/run, /proc, /dev, ... and mounted directories in general), ... I'm not sure. Good hunting.

Comment: Thanks. I've also updated the main post with `du` output of /root dir, looks strange to me but i don't really understand it.

Maybe you'll figure something out from that

Comment: Oh... Nice catch. Can you update your post including the output of `ls -lh /root`

Comment: You can probably get rid of the `tmp_*` file you're telling us about, just use `rm -f /root/tmp_iFC*`

Comment: even `rm -f /root/tmp*`

Comment: That freed up 13G, wow.
Not sure how to mark *a comment* as an answer, please tell me so i can do the least i can do :)

Comment: No worry, thanks. You should be left with about 8G on your rootfs, which is still a lot and could use some further investigations. Although you should be able to roll the dices on that upgrade. Good luck ;)

Comment: Were you running software as root? Generally /root does not have much, but is the /home write location if you use software as root not as a user.

Comment: I'd be surprised if OP managed to free more than a few megabytes by purging left-over configuration files of previously removed packages. -1

Comment: Sorry? Have you ever purged several "removed" kernels at once? Including headers, over time, ... this can add up to several gigs. When my ubuntus are getting out of space, purging is usually the only thing I need to do.